# How to make popup look at the centre of the screen?

Tags: css, popup, alignment

When i click a link, a pop up comes out. The thing is that it is not aligned to the centre of the screen. By the way my code also helps the website (and the pop up) to look perfectly in a mobile version.

The HTML code :

```
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="exampleModal">POP UP</a>

<div id="exampleModal" class="reveal-modal">
     <h2>POP UP</h2>
     <p>
     <font size="4">window window window.window window window. window.
         </font>
    </p>
    <a class="close-reveal-modal">×</a>
</div>
```

The css code :

```
 .reveal-modal     
  {
        background:#e1e1e1; 
        visibility:hidden;
        display:none;
        top:100px; 
        left:50%; 
        width:820px; 
        position:absolute; 
        z-index:41;
        padding:30px; 
        -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
        -moz-box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
        box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)
  }
```

I tried putting some right:50% as well but it didn't work. Shouldn't left work ?

Comment: Either use jQuery to calc / set the left, or put popup in a container that is full-width, and has text-align: center on it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

These are the changes to make:

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
    background-color: rgba(22,22,22,0.5); /* complimenting your modal colors */
}
#container:target {
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
}
.reveal-modal {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 25%;
}
    /* Remove the left: 50% */
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#container">Reveal</a>
<div id="container">
    <div id="exampleModal" class="reveal-modal">
    ........
    <a href="#">Close Modal</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle - Updated with CSS only](http://jsfiddle.net/lacoolj/vTsRk/3/)

Comment: I don't want to add jss because I will have to change some things. Isn;t that possible with css only?

Comment: @ApoloRadomer there ya go.  Updated the jfiddle for you too so you can see it in action.

Comment: check the page [link](http://aasiskos.webpages.auth.gr/NAUTILUS/prosopiko.html) in 2 minutes from now

Comment: Very nice job.  That modal inspired me to make some of my own stuff tonight and haven't stopped yet lol

Comment: @ApoloRadomer link is broken. Not accessible.

Comment: @sky91 My server was down. I will have to check again

Comment: Hi demo has Error 502

Answer (score 26):

In order to get the popup exactly centered, it's a simple matter of applying a negative top margin of half the div height, and a negative left margin of half the div width. For this example, like so:

```
.div {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: This should be applied to container div or modal div ?

Comment: directly to to modal div

Answer (score 7):

If the effect you want is to center in the center of the screen no matter where you've scrolled to, it's even simpler than that:

In your CSS use (for example)

```
div.centered{
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  position:fixed; 
  top: calc(50% - 25px); // half of width
  left: calc(50% - 50px); // half of height
}
```

No JS required.

Comment: You do minus 50px for left position. What if width of my pop up is not fixed (some % value)?

Comment: Good solution, but thin *historical* support in some mobile browsers (source: https://caniuse.com/#search=calc)

Comment: the `calc` is so simple that you can use negative margins instead e.g. `top: 50%; margin-top: -25px; // half of height`

Answer (score 1):

```
/*--------  Bootstrap Modal Popup in Center of Screen --------------*/
/*---------------extra css------*/
.modal {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
.modal:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: -4px;
}
.modal-dialog {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
/*----- Modal Popup -------*/
<div class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" >
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
                <h5 class="modal-title">Header</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
               body here     
             </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">            
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please consider augmenting your answer next time :)