# How do I ensure my pop up is in the middle of the screen? No matter where I am scrolled to on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am following a tutorial for a basic contact pop up form, which works fine.

However, the pop up is fixed to the centre of the screen at the top. How do I fix this so that my pop up is fixed to the centre of the screen, no matter where you are scrolled to on the page.

```js
document.getElementById('git-btn').addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector('.bg-modal').style.display = "flex";
});

document.querySelector('.close').addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector('.bg-modal').style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
.bg-modal {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba (0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.modal-content {
  width: 500px;
  height: 550px;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  border: 4px solid #4161BF;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 40px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<button id="git-btn">Show modal</button>
<div class="bg-modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="close">+</div>
    <i class="fas fa-envelope fa-2x" style="color:#4161BF"></i>
    <form action="">

      <div class="form-name">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
      </div>

      <div class="form-email">
        <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail">
      </div>

      <div class="form-input">
        <textarea rows="2" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should take a look at the CSS [`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) property, specifically [`fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#fixed)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make popup look at the centre of the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19467693/how-to-make-popup-look-at-the-centre-of-the-screen)

Comment: @Titus This works, but I have two other problems. When I trigger it at the very bottom of the screen (in the footer), the items inside aren't useable. I have to scroll back up slightly to enter any fields or even close the pop up. Also, the the other links/buttons in the footer are still active and seem to overlap the pop up. Do you think it would be best to use some javascript to hide the footer once i click the pop up?

Comment: You can use CSS [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) to make sure the pop-up is on top of everything. I'm not sure I understand what the other problem is so I don't know how you could fix it.

Comment: @Titus z-index fixes everything, thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the bg-modal's position to fixed, set it top: 0, left: 0, also in the JavaScript file make it so it is displayed as a block. Now in the modal-content, and also in every element you want to be perfectly centered, set the position to absolute, top: 50%, left: 50%, and then transform: translate(-50%, -50%).

```js
document.getElementById('git-btn').addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.querySelector('.bg-modal').style.display = "block";
});

document.querySelector('.close').addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.querySelector('.bg-modal').style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
.bg-modal{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgba (0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.modal-content{
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    border: 4px solid #4161BF;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<button id="git-btn">Open</button>
<button class="close">Close</button>
<div class="bg-modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="close">+</div>
        <i class="fas fa-envelope fa-2x" style="color:#4161BF"></i>
        <form action="">
            <div class="form-name">
            <input type="text"  placeholder="Name">
            </div>

            <div class="form-email">
            <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail">
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-input">
            <textarea rows="2"  placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```